# How does one configure API Gateway to return "Not Found" rather than "Missing Authentication Token"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

According to [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=192977), when an api gets invoked with a resource that does not exist, it returns "Missing Authentication Token", status 403.

I'd like it to return a 404 "Not Found" to my users, but I've not found anything that suggests how this would be corrected, save for changing the return message and status for "Missing Authentication Token" under Gateway Responses, and that seems like bad practice.

What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your api is open (No AWS_IAM or custom authorizer on any resource), then mapping MISSING_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN gateway response would not change any behavior.

If your API is secured, then you can use RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND gateway response. You will still see Missing authentication token on unauthenticated requests for a 404.

404s are mapped to 403 for unauthenticated requests to not leak information about which resource paths are valid and which ones aren't. We don't provide any setting to disable this.

Comment: But I have configured a permissive resource policy, API Gateway should respect it.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-examples.html